# Use regex in Python to rule out string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm using pandas to clean the data as below:

```
s3 = pd.DataFrame({'title':["intermediate" ,"Basmati/sadri" ,"temperate japonica" ,"Temperate japonica" , "Japonica" ,"Tropical japonica" ,"Aromatic (basmati/sandri type" , "indica" , "Aus/boro" , "Aus" ,"aus" ,"japonica" , "tropical japnica", "" , "Indica" , "Intermediate type" ]})

s3.title.replace(r".*[Jj]ap(o)?nica$", "japonica" ,inplace=True,regex=True)

s3.title.replace(r"Indica", "indica" ,inplace=True,regex=True)

print s3
```

And I got:

```
                        title
0                    intermediate
1                   Basmati/sadri
2                        japonica
3                        japonica
4                        japonica
5                        japonica
6   Aromatic (basmati/sandri type
7                          indica
8                        Aus/boro
9                             Aus
10                            aus
11                       japonica
12                       japonica
13                               
14                         indica
15              Intermediate type
```

I want to replace string like:

```
if string not in  ['japonica', "indica"] :
    string = 'others'
```

But how to do it as regex:

```
s3.title.replace(r"some regex", "others" ,inplace=True,regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. It uses three cases, separated by or (`|`) operators.

- a negative lookahead to ensure the title does not start with either `japonica` or `indica`, with some other characters required.
- an or statement to ensure that if the title does start with `japonica` or `indica`, there are other characters afterwards, confirming that the string is not `japonica` or `indica` alone.
- an empty string.

  ```
  s3.title.replace(r'^(?!japonica|indica).+$|^(japonica|indica).+$|^$', "others", inplace=True, regex=True)
  ```

Comment: great~ But line13 is blank, can it be added to the regex?

Comment: I tried s3.title.replace(r'^(?!japonica|indica).+|(japonica|indica).+$', "others", inplace=True, regex=True), line13 is still blank. I'll need to write an extra line to replace the blank to 'others'. How can regex match a blank line?

Comment: s3.title.replace(r'^(?!japonica|indica).+|(japonica|indica).+|$', "others", inplace=True, regex=True) will get:  japonicaothers and  indicaothers

Comment: @milowang I edited my answer to include what you need - try adding a `|` immediately before the `$`.

Comment: @milowang I have modified the regex to (hopefully) accommodate an empty string.

Comment: s3.title.replace('', "others", inplace=True, regex=True) is needed

Comment: https://github.com/kaiwang0112006/simplejupyter/blob/master/pandas%20regex.ipynb     awesome~